# Colorir texto dentro de "tag"

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Bom, tenho um Rich edit e estou usando-o como changelog, e gostaria que todo texto contigo em -><-, ficasse de uma cor específica.
Exemplo, em:

```
->10/10/2014<-
```

o 10/10/2014 ficaria de uma cor específica.
Como posso fazer isso?
Ps: estou usando idhttp para baixar o log:

```
sRichEdit1.Text := IdHTTP2.Get('www.blabla.com/changelog.txt');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[ATUALIZAÇÃO]**

Para aplicar o estilo a um RichEdit já preenchido o seguinte algoritmo poderia ser utilizado:

```
procedure ApplyStyleWhenMatchPattern(Edit: TRichEdit; const TokenStart,
  TokenEnd: string; MatchColor: TColor);
var
  StartPos, EndPos, OffSet, Len: Integer;
begin
  Len:= Length(Edit.Text);
  StartPos:= Edit.FindText(TokenStart, 0, Len, []);
  EndPos:= Edit.FindText(TokenEnd, Succ(StartPos), Len, []);
  while EndPos <> -1 do
  begin
    Edit.SelStart:= StartPos+ Length(TokenStart);
    Edit.SelLength:= EndPos - StartPos -Length(TokenEnd) ;
    Edit.SelAttributes.Color:= MatchColor;

    OffSet:= Succ(EndPos);
    StartPos:= Edit.FindText(TokenStart, OffSet, Len, []);
    EndPos:=   Edit.FindText(TokenEnd,   Succ(OffSet), Len, []);
  end;
end;
```

Para aplicar efetivamente execute o método:

```
ApplyStylesWhenMatchPattern(RichEdit1, '->', '<-', clRed);
```

Esse algoritmo não prevê intersecção de comandos `->->`, se for necessário tal funcionalidade, deverá ser revisto.

---

Para atingir seu objetivo, você precisa trabalhar com as propriedades `SelAttributes` e `SelText` do `TRichEdit`. Encapsule sua função de Log e faça da seguinte forma:

```
 procedure LogIt(const AMessage: String);
 begin
    RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color:= clBlack;
    RichEdit1.SelText:= '->';
    RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color:= clRed;
    RichEdit1.SelText:= AMessage;
    RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color:= clBlack;
    RichEdit1.SelText:= '<-';
    RichEdit1.Lines.Add(''); 
 end;
```

Você poderia ainda utilizar a cor do texto customizadamente, exemplo, para Erro: Vermelho, Aviso: Amarelo. Nesses casos, a função acima receberia uma cor.

```
 procedure LogIt(const AMessage: String; AColor: TColor);
 begin
    RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color:= clBlack;
    RichEdit1.SelText:= '->';
    RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color:= AColor;
    RichEdit1.SelText:= AMessage;
    RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color:= clBlack;
    RichEdit1.SelText:= '<-';
    RichEdit1.Lines.Add(''); 
 end;
```

Comment: No caso, e se o texto ja estiver escrito? 
O changelog é baixado do servidor, logo ele ja vem escrito.

Comment: Vou postar outra resposta

Comment: Poste outra pergunta, pois o algoritmo é totalmente diferente, por exemplo. Poderá aparecer 2 vezes "->asdas-<" na mesma linha?